# How to insert border on material widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm beginner in flutter and I cant insert a border rounded on Material Widget. I've inserted the propriety `borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(6.0),` but I cant see I'm doing wrong:

My code:

```
Widget _buildCategoryItem(index) {
return new GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    onTabCategory(index);
  },
  child: new Center(
    child: new Container(
      margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
      child: new Material(
        elevation: 2.0,
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
        child: new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 12.0, top: 7.0, bottom: 7.0, right: 12.0),
          color: _category_selected == index
              ? Colors.orange[800]
              : Colors.orange[500],
          child: new Text(
            _categorys[index],
            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

The category labels are formatted as square but I want to make it with border rounded:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You can insert a border to `Material widget` by its shape property

```
  Material(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 1),
      ),
      child: const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text('Material widget'),
      ),
    ),
```

[image: Material Widget image]

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution. I can use the `ClipRRect` Widget to wrap the Material Widget and make the corners rounded.

My code fixed:

```
Widget _buildCategoryItem(index) {
return new GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    onTabCategory(index);
  },
  child: new Center(
    child: new Container(
      margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
      child: new ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
        child: new Material(
          elevation: 2.0,
          child: new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 12.0, top: 7.0, bottom: 7.0, right: 12.0),
            color: _category_selected == index
                ? Colors.orange[800]
                : Colors.orange[500],
            child: new Text(
              _categorys[index],
              style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your code is the same that I wrote in my question